# Using StatSample in Ruby to Create Multiple CrossTabs of categorical and numeric variables with chisq

Tags: ruby, statistics, crosstab

I'm working on a public access health data visualization project, and my program currently provides descriptive statistics for 15 categorical variables (stored as strings) and 2 numeric variables (stored as floats). Now I'm trying to create basic cross tabulations of each variable by each other variable, with column and row totals and chisq for each. After looking around for awhile, statsample seemed to be the best option based on this documentation ( http://ruby-statsample.rubyforge.org/statsample/Statsample/Crosstab.html ), but I'm having trouble getting the crosstab function to work. So I have two questions: 1) can anyone help me get the basic crosstab functionality going, and 2) is there some sexy 'ruby' way to semi-automate the process of running each of the crosstabs to avoid hard coding (17 X 17) = 289 cross tabulations? I'm happy to do that if necessary, but it seems like there must be a better way!

Below is an example of the code I've been attempting to use, and the contents of the arrays being used:

**array_hosp_group**

CENTRAL VERMONT HOSPITAL

CENTRAL VERMONT HOSPITAL

CENTRAL VERMONT HOSPITAL

SOUTHWESTERN VERMONT MEDICAL CENTER

SOUTHWESTERN VERMONT MEDICAL CENTER

BRATTLEBORO MEMORIAL HOSPITAL

BRATTLEBORO MEMORIAL HOSPITAL

FLETCHER ALLEN HEALTH CARE

FLETCHER ALLEN HEALTH CARE

...

**array_dis_group**

HOME - OWN OR FAMILY CARE

HOME - OWN OR FAMILY CARE

TO A SKILLED NURSING FACILITY

HOME - OWN OR FAMILY CARE

HOME - OWN OR FAMILY CARE

TO ANOTHER ACUTE HOSPITAL

...

```
hum_stat_hosp = array_hosp_group.to_scale
hum_stat_dis = array_dis_group.to_scale
hosp_dis = Statsample::Crosstab.new(hum_stat_hosp,hum_stat_dis)
puts hosp_dis.summary
```

This code returns the error: 
Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/statsample-1.3.0/lib/statsample/crosstab.rb:82:in`matrix_expected':undefined method`*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/statsample-1.3.0/li/statsample/crosstab.rb:81:in `collect' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/statsample-1.3.0/lib/statsample/crosstab.rb:81:in`matrix_expected'

I've also tried using the following code, and gotten the same error message:

```
rb=ReportBuilder.new
rb.add(Statsample::Crosstab.new(hum_stat_hosp,hum_stat_dis)
rb.save_html("location")
```

I've also tried adding

```
opts=Hash.new
```

to each of the above code attempts, based on the documentation, with no difference in error message. I've searched around a fair bit on here and other sites, but I can't seem to find any examples of crosstab implementation in statsample.

Thank you! Any and all help is much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The fast answer is use

```
hum_stat_hosp = array_hosp_group.to_vector
hum_stat_dis = array_dis_group.to_vector
```

Because Crosstab doesn't work with scalar. That is a bug that I should fix :P